# CSV cleanup: remove all in col after (

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence, parsing, subsequence

#### Problem

Given a file with:

```
56 (65%), 33(75%), , 44, "“hello”,(5) world", goodbye
89 (25%), 33(75%), , 44, "hello world", goodbye
92 (97%), 33(75%), , 44, "hello world", goodbye
```

#### Goal

Write back to that file with:

```
56, 33, , 44, "“hello”,(5) world", goodbye
89, 33, , 44, "hello world", goodbye
92, 33, , 44, "hello world", goodbye
```

#### Example implementation [Python 518 bytes]

```
import csv
from sys import argv
from itertools import takewhile, imap


with open(argv[1], 'r+') as f0:
    r = csv.reader(f0, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    w = csv.writer(f0, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    rows = tuple(imap(lambda line: ''.join(
        '{}\0'.format(''.join(
            takewhile(lambda ch: ch != '(', col))).rstrip() for col in line), r))
    f0.seek(0)
    tuple(imap(lambda line: w.writerow(line.split('\0')), rows))
```

Comment: Are we required to respect the full CSV specification, including quoted values, or are we allowed to skip that part?

Comment: Yes, support for quoted values must be respected.

Comment: Ah, drat. I would have been able to do it in 12 bytes otherwise.

Comment: Aww :P - so close

Comment: I can't see why quoted values must be respected, as I'm given a file that does not contain them. Maybe you should specify better the task.

Comment: Fixed. Extra kudos if you remove only parenthesised numerical with/without `%` from the CSV.

Comment: If we have to support quoted values, you should add a test case where they matter, e.g., one with a quoted comma. What should happen if the brackets are quoted?

Comment: Also, how much whitespace can occur before the opening bracket? Does all of it have to be removed?

Comment: Finally, will the opening bracket always have a mtaching closing bracket?

Comment: Updated examples. Parentheses are guaranteed to be balanced.

Comment: Would you mind providing a more detail description of the problem? I see what the output is but I am assuming the steps in between... many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Perl: 15 Bytes +1 for -p option**

```
s/ ?\([^,"]+//g
```

**Usage:**

```
perl -pe 's/ ?\([^,"]+//g' file.csv
```